# My Laravel Auth::attempt Is Work localhost but on my website not logged

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

Hey All Programmers I have A Big problem 
I have A project on my localhost xampp 
my Auth::attempt is work from my local host 
but before uploading my website is not work whay 
i Change my key generate from app.php 
And Testing all cods from controller login 
this is my code login email and password is fillable from User model
and i added my primary key protected from model User
I Checking My Auth.php is Good

## This is my attempt code

```
public function PostLogin()
{
    $inputs = Input::all();
    $rules  = array('email'=>'required|email','pass'=>'required');
    $valid = Validator::make($inputs,$rules);

    if($valid->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($valid);
    }else{
        $crec = array('email'=>$inputs['email'],'password'=>Input::get('pass'));
      if(Auth::attempt($crec))
      {
        return Redirect::to('/');
      }else{
        return View::make('users.login')->with('title',Lang::get('users.login'));
      }

    }
}
```

/*===============================================*/

```
protected $fillable  = array('email','username','password');
protected $primaryKey = "id";

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
```

}

=====================

please i want any help thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connected to the online database with its right type and link and credentials in the `/app/config/database.php` and make sure to remove the `http://` from the link.

Comment: You're saying it works on the localhost but it doesn't online on the hosting server. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: yes i say that but i am sure to connection database and i have a register new user page is work  but i want knowing what about for this error not login in my web site but login in localhost is work